# Is this the correct form of the time dependent wavefunction of the 1D particle in a box?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I would like to learn about the Schrodinger wavefunction for the 1 Dimensional particle-in-a-box.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Position_and_momentum_probability_distributions) the different modes of this wavefunction have been animated.

[image]

From [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/05.5%3A_Particle_in_Boxes/Particle_in_a_1-Dimensional_box) the solution of 1D particle in a box is derived to be:

[image: here]

When different values of n are substituted, n=1, n=2, n=3..., we get the different real-valued standing wave modes similar to the ones shown in the animation.

However, the time evolution is not derived in the above equation. Is the following the correct form of the time dependent wavefunction?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644899/time-evolution-for-the-harmonic-oscillator-wave-functions/

Comment: @ConnorBehan i'm sorry i'm not familiar with the breve notation used in the link. is the above edit the correct explicit formula for different modes n and different time t?

Comment: Are you asking if the Wikipedia article is correct?

Comment: What is “breve notation”?

Comment: @Ghoster thank you. Is En used to plot the graph or not?

Comment: @Ghoster Euler complex exponentials scares me by the look :)

Comment: If complex exponentials scare you, you may not yet be ready to learn quantum mechanics.

Comment: Or else, through exposure to quantum mechanics, complex exponentials will stop scaring you ;) as you get a lot of practice with them

Comment: @doublefelix thank you!

Comment: @James This is how it happened for me ;) Anyway feel free to ask any followup questions.

Comment: *Is En used to plot the graph or not?* Yes. The energy determines the frequency with which the curves oscillate in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you gave

$$\psi = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})$$

is a solution for the time-independent Schrödinger equation (TISE). That is an equation whose solutions give energy eigenstates, and whose solutions can be used in the (more difficult) process of solving the full, time-dependent Schrödinger equation (TDSE), which actually governs time evolution.

How the state evolves according to the TDSE depends completely on your initial state $\psi(t=0)$. The animations choose specifically the initial states which change almost not at all, so the solution is simple. Those nearly-unchanging solutions are precisely the ones for which $\psi(t=0)$ is a solution of the TISE.

The way such simple solutions work is as follows: If some function $\psi_n$ is a solution to the TISE, then the function
$$\psi_n e^{-iE_n t/\hbar}$$
solves the TDSE, where $E_n$ is the corresponding energy for that solution. Notice that for such states the probability density in $x$ doesn't change in time, because $$|\Psi(t)|^2 =|\psi_n e^{-i E_n t / \hbar}|^2 = |\psi_n |^2 |e^{-i E_n t / \hbar}|^2 = |\psi_n|^2 \times 1 $$

So the time evolution for your example is

$$\Psi(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})e^{-it E_n /\hbar}$$

and from there the real and imaginary parts can be plotted.

Generally however, solutions to the TDSE *do* change their probability density in $x$ over time. One well-known time-dependent solution to the TDSE is [the gaussian wave packet](https://www.cond-mat.de/teaching/QM/JSim/wpack.html).

Edit: I forgot a negative sign in the exponent.

Comment: thank you vm. it works like a charm. If you happen to have the explicit formula for the 2D particle in a box case, I have asked the question in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/739978/time-dependent-schrodinger-equation-for-2d-particle-in-a-box

Comment: I think the solution is separable, and separates into just the product of the individual solutions in each dimension. That product does not need to have values of $n$ which are the same for each factor.